# how to align bootstrap column middle of the div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[this is my demo page](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/EKQBqq) and I have bootstrap column inside my div which parent class is absolute but my column is not middle of carousel..how to do that ?

and I add image to what I want to do
[image]

you can see my structure

html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="myDiv ">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">left column..</div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">right column..</div>
          </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://www.aurumhotels.com.tr/resimler/normal/2015-08/FirmaArkaBanner1_4BuFjQUcCp3yALBpDUxLsignature.jpg" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.aurumhotels.com.tr/resimler/normal/2015-12/FirmaArkaBanner1_Isrgao2xv47jrJVBsf2Hfirmaarkabanner2.png" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.my-slider{
      background:#FFF;
      position: absolute;;
      top:0;
      z-index:1;
}
.item img {
      width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
.myDiv{
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  z-index:1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
```

}

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqWmYB

Comment: interesting and great..on codepen its working very well but on my desktop its working as before

Comment: @ani_css, this works great at centering. However bootstrap's container loses its width of 1170px. Were you expecting to keep the container's width of 1170px and center that div?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and fix the vw (Viewport width) according to your need.

```
.myDiv{
      position: absolute;
      background:#fff;
      z-index:1;
      width:50vw;
      left:25vw;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nikmahes/pen/GZxYpB

Comment: so thanks but project must be cross browser it has to be work ie 9+ :))

Answer (score 0):

Your `.myDiv` requires some changes, add those properties:

```
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

and move background to `.myDiv .container`

Answer (score -1):

since the parent is absolute positioned, it will need to be given a width of 100% for its children to be centered within container. I'm going to assume my-slider is really myDiv:

```
    .myDiv{
      background:#FFF;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      z-index:1;
      width:100%;    
}
```